# "400 Bad Request" exception error with optional parameter using JQuery Ajax with Web API

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-web-api

I read the ASP.NET documentation and I'm getting there but I get "400 Bad Request" exception error that I do not understand.

What is it about the "optional parameter" error, that cause exception error and what's the workaround to it?  The exception error is

--snip--
{"Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String Post(Int32)' in 'BIO.Dealer.WebApp.WebApi.Member.AmazonServerDigitalLoanJacketController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."}
--snip--

Source code below.

```
//Web API Config
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "MemberApi",
            routeTemplate: "WebApi/Member/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}

//JQuery
var jsonRequest = { "Id": 3, "Name": "Scott Fletcher"};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false, /*false, //This need to be synchronous to the client can wait for webserver response...*/
    url: https://localhost:44301/WebApi/Member/AmazonServerDigitalLoanJacket/Upload",
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonRequest),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (parmData, parmTextStatus, parmXmlHttpRequest) {
        //alert("AjaxStatus: " + parmTextStatus + "\nReadyState - " + parmXmlHttpRequest.readyState + "\nStatus: " + parmXmlHttpRequest.status + "\nStatusText: " + parmXmlHttpRequest.statusText + "\nResponseText: " + parmXmlHttpRequest.responseText);
        jsonResponse = parmData;
    },
    error: function (parmXmlHttpRequest, parmTextStatus, parmErrorThrown) {
        //alert("AjaxStatus: " + parmTextStatus + "\nReadyState - " + parmXmlHttpRequest.readyState + "\nStatus: " + parmXmlHttpRequest.status + "\nStatusText: " + parmXmlHttpRequest.statusText + "\nResponseText: " + parmXmlHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
});

//Web API Controller
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class AmazonServerDigitalLoanJacketController : ApiController
{
    [ActionName("Upload")]  //Upload File(s)...
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post(Foo parmFoo)
    {
        return "object of ID " + parmFoo.Id.ToString() + " (Upload) & Name: " + parmFoo.Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing multiple parameters when your method only accepts one. But it chokes on the default route before that. Put those data values in a form and serialize it so it may be interpreted as the object you expect. Otherwise ask for 2 parameters, an int id and a string name, then you can create the object yourself.

Comment: How do you changed it to accept JSON request instead?  LIke this example I saw at http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/using-custom-action-names-in-asp.net-web-api.htm

Comment: You need to serialize a form with two inputs whose names match the properties of your object, that's the binding magic that will allow you to map to an object. Or edit your Post() method to accept Id and a Name, so the 2 params you are passing actually match a method signature.

Comment: Okay, I added the JSON serialize in the $.ajax data request.  That doesn't seems to do the trick.  The Id & Name in JSON object match the one on the controller.  Still same error.  I updated the example above.  It's saying the Id is null.

Comment: JSON Serialize does help.  I found the problem, I need to add the "/{action}" to the WebApiConfig's routing config.   That fixed my issue.  Thank for your help.